# why doesn't this javascript code work document.getElementsByClassName("para")[0].innerHTML.style.visibility = "hidden";

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code that will make the relevant paragraph disappear:

`var first = paragraph[0].innerHTML = " "`

but can't figure out why the following line of code won't make the paragraph disappear:

`document.getElementsByClassName("para")[0].innerHTML.style.visibility = "hidden";`

Comment: It could be for a number of reasons. It would help if you would tell us _what_'s going wrong. Is there an error in the console? What does it say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need `innerHTML`, use

```
document.getElementsByClassName('para')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName("para")[0].innerHTML`  returns a string, you need the first element with class para, remove `.innerHTML` and it will work.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("para")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
```